# The meaning of attend in a specific context

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

In a software product, when an unable exception occurs, the app displays a error message containing, among others, the following sentence:

> The error has been logged and the support team will attend to it as soon as possible.

What does it mean? I don't understand the usage of the term *attend* in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Attend to](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/attend-to) is a *phrasal verb*, it means *to deal with something or someone*. In this context, it means to deal with the error.

Comment: Specifically, to attend to something is to give it your attention.